# Tomcat - EclipseLink-4002 SQLNestedException: Cannot create JDBC driver of class '' for connect URL 'null'

Tags: tomcat, jpa, tomcat7, eclipselink, jpa-2.0

Okay, I have been working on this on and off for about a week. I have found a lot of information online and tried a lot of different things, but none of it has helped me, so please. Any suggestions are greatly appreciated.

I am trying to get EclipseLink working on Tomcat. I have got this working locally in Tomcat, but when I deploy to a server, I get errors. I am using Tomcat 7.0.55, EclipseLink 2.3.2, and JPA 2.0 both locally and on the server.

I have added these jars to TOMCAT_HOME/lib. I am not convinced that all of these are needed, so please let me know whether they are or not.

- db2jcc.jar
- db2jcc_license_cu.jar
- eclipselink-2.3.2.jar
- javax.persistence-2.0.0.jar

Here is my current code.

**pom.xml**

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.eclipse.persistence</groupId>
    <artifactId>eclipselink</artifactId>
    <version>2.3.2</version>
    <exclusions>
        <exclusion>
            <artifactId>commonj.sdo</artifactId>
            <groupId>commonj.sdo</groupId>
        </exclusion>
    </exclusions>
</dependency>
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.eclipse.persistence</groupId>
    <artifactId>javax.persistence</artifactId>
    <version>2.0.0</version>
</dependency>
```

**web.xml**

```
<resource-ref>
    <description>MYDS connection</description>
    <res-ref-name>jdbc/MYDS</res-ref-name>
    <res-type>javax.sql.DataSource</res-type>
    <res-auth>Container</res-auth>
</resource-ref>
```

**context.xml**
I have removed connection information, but I am positive my configuration is correct since it works locally.

```
<Resource name="jdbc/MYDS"
    auth="Container"
    type="javax.sql.DataSource"
    username="username"
    password="password"
    driverClassName="com.ibm.db2.jcc.DB2Driver"
    url="jdbc:db2://<hostname>:<port>/MYDS"
    maxActive="15"
    maxIdle="3" />
```

**persistence.xml**

```
<persistence-unit name="MYDS" transaction-type="RESOURCE_LOCAL">
    <provider>org.eclipse.persistence.jpa.PersistenceProvider</provider>
    <non-jta-data-source>java:/comp/env/jdbc/MFMFB302</non-jta-data-source>
    <!-- ================== File Mappings ================== -->
    <mapping-file>META-INF/orm/MYDS.xml</mapping-file>
    <exclude-unlisted-classes>false</exclude-unlisted-classes>

    <!-- ================== Entities ================== -->
    <class>model.model1</class>
    <class>model.model2</class>

    <properties>
        <property name="eclipselink.weaving" value="false" />
        <property name="eclipselink.ddl-generation.output-mode" value="sql-script"/>
        <property name="eclipselink.logging.level" value="FINE"/>
        <property name="eclipselink.target-database" value="DB2"/>
    </properties>
</persistence-unit>
```

I have tried connecting two different ways.

**connection - using intitialcontext**

```
Context initCtx = new InitialContext();
Context envCtx = (Context) initCtx.lookup("java:comp/env");
DataSource ds = (DataSource) envCtx.lookup("jdbc/MYDS");
Connection conn = ds.getConnection();
conn.close();
```

**connection - using jpa**

```
EntityManagerFactory emf = Persistence.createEntityManagerFactory( "MYDS" );
JpaEntityManager entityManager = (JpaEntityManager) emf.createEntityManager();
```

But I am getting:

**Error**

```
javax.persistence.PersistenceException: Exception [EclipseLink-4002] (Eclipse Persistence Services - 2.3.2.v20111125-r10461): org.eclipse.persistence.exceptions.DatabaseException
Internal Exception: org.apache.tomcat.dbcp.dbcp.SQLNestedException: Cannot create JDBC driver of class '' for connect URL 'null'
Error Code: 0
    at org.eclipse.persistence.internal.jpa.EntityManagerSetupImpl.deploy(EntityManagerSetupImpl.java:517)
    at org.eclipse.persistence.internal.jpa.EntityManagerFactoryDelegate.getDatabaseSession(EntityManagerFactoryDelegate.java:188)
    at org.eclipse.persistence.internal.jpa.EntityManagerFactoryDelegate.createEntityManagerImpl(EntityManagerFactoryDelegate.java:277)
    at org.eclipse.persistence.internal.jpa.EntityManagerFactoryImpl.createEntityManagerImpl(EntityManagerFactoryImpl.java:294)
    at org.eclipse.persistence.internal.jpa.EntityManagerFactoryImpl.createEntityManager(EntityManagerFactoryImpl.java:272)
```

**with root cause**

```
Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
    at sun.jdbc.odbc.JdbcOdbcDriver.getProtocol(JdbcOdbcDriver.java:524)
    at sun.jdbc.odbc.JdbcOdbcDriver.knownURL(JdbcOdbcDriver.java:493)
    at sun.jdbc.odbc.JdbcOdbcDriver.acceptsURL(JdbcOdbcDriver.java:307)
    at java.sql.DriverManager.getDriver(DriverManager.java:262)
    at org.apache.tomcat.dbcp.dbcp.BasicDataSource.createConnectionFactory(BasicDataSource.java:1437)
```

What I am getting from this is that Tomcat can't find my context.xml. Is that right?

I know there is also documentation that puts the resource in server.xml and a ResourceLink element in context.xml. I have tried this, but I get exactly the same error.

Comment: At first sight everything seems fine to me, but Could you try this


`dataSource = (DataSource) new InitialContext().lookup("java:comp/env/jdbc/MYDS");`

Comment: Thanks. I made that change but also moved my datasource into the server's context.xml to see if the resources were even being read. This worked using initialcontext, so I think the problem is that, for some reason, Tomcat isn't reading my context.xml. I haven't tested the with Eclipselink yet. My app is on a scheduled deploy, so I am making small changes and testing as they get deployed.